# Center of rotation of a scene in VTK

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I have a model that when I translate it using the mouse, and then try to rotate it, it rotates on the center of the scene, and not the model, and looks very awkward. Paraview rotates on the center of the model by default, but they has so much abstraction in their code that it is impossible to read. I've looked and looked and looked and there doesn't seem to be anyone asking about this and therefore no solutions or things to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of transformations is important, you need to read up on linear algebra with matrices.  In a nutshell, you need to translate your model back to the scene centre, rotate, and apply the translation again - pushing the object back to it's original location.

Comment: Thanks. I think I may have seen this on some mail thread, but it wasn't nearly as clean and evident. I'll try to implement it and see what happens.

Comment: It should be noted that VTK/ParaView uses a pre multiply Transform class. More information can be found at http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTransform.html